# проблема с движением кнопки c#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня двигающаяся кнопка  и 4 статичные. Эта двигающаяся кнопка не должна проходить сквозь другие. Но в чём-то есть проблема, и она проходит

```
 if (_rectangles.All(x => !x.IntersectsWith(button2.Bounds)) || (_lastKey != Keys.None && _lastKey != e.KeyCode))
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.A:


                        button2.Location = new Point(button2.Location.X - 5, button2.Location.Y);

                    break;
                case Keys.S:
                    if (button2.Location.Y + button2.Size.Height < this.ClientSize.Height)
                        button2.Location = new Point(button2.Location.X, button2.Location.Y + 5);
                    break;
                case Keys.W:
                    if (button2.Location.Y + 1 > 5)
                        button2.Location = new Point(button2.Location.X, button2.Location.Y - 5);
                    break;
                case Keys.D:
                    if (button2.Location.X + button2.Size.Width < this.ClientSize.Width)
                        button2.Location = new Point(button2.Location.X + 5, button2.Location.Y);
                    break;

            }
        }
        else
            _lastKey = e.KeyCode;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

нужно добавить `_lastKey = Keys.None;`